# Base64.getDecoder() returns different answer with the same string input

Tags: java, base64

I'm confused about this issue. Platform is on win7 java8.

Sample code:

```
String encryptedData = "0019ZfGO0nefTb2kIuHO0M3hGO09ZfGF";
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] dataByte = decoder.decode(encryptedData);
System.out.println(dataByte);
dataByte = decoder.decode(encryptedData);
System.out.println(dataByte);
```

The output:

```
[B@15db9742
[B@6d06d69c
```

The exact input got different result. 
Don't know if there's anyway to clear the status and make the result consistent every time?

Thanks!

Comment: `decoder.decode(encryptedData);` returns a new `byte[]`. What you're printing is the reference of that array, which is different each time decode is called. The data they both contain will be the same though.

Comment: See [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: I understand the problem now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Java, arrays don't override `toString()`, so if you try to print one directly, you get the "className + @ + the hex of the `hashCode` of the array", as defined by `Object.toString()`
Note:Just printing the array by reference variable means you are calling the `toString()` method of that array object.
As `decoder.decode(encryptedData)` returns a `new byte[]` every-time, therefore it gives a different value when you just print the reference variable.
Ex: `System.out.println(dataByte);//output:[B@15db9742`

You can use the standard library functions to print the contains of the array. There are many ways to achieve this. Just some examples are below:
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataByte));`
`System.out.println(dataByte.toList());`